# rails link_to causing 304 not modified

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, http-status-code-304

I have a line in view that
`<%= link_to 'text', path_to_controller_action, remote: true, class: "button" %>`

that will trigger the controller action but work like an AJAX call so the user will stay on the page.

It was working fine for a while but suddenly, this GET request via link_to
is giving me 304 not modified response...

The action is still performed but the 304 response is preventing rails from performing other actions that followed the controller action...

I have a `controller_action.js.erb` file that makes AJAX calls to other methods in the controller to check if the above action triggered by link_to is finished... all was working fine until I started getting 304 and I did not change any code.

Any suggestions on how to not get 304 but get 200 like it used to?

Im assuming it has to do with Ajax calls and caching... these are not my strengths please help out!

Comment: Add your controller.

Comment: the method in the controller called by `link_to` works fine. problem is with rails not executing the corresponding `.js.erb` file at all! I believe this is because link_to results in HTTP 304 status code. I'm suspecting something to with caching... any suggestions @SebastiánPalma ?

Comment: was this solved?